# I need a module like Pageflip

Tags: 6

I need a stable Drupal module version like [Pageflip](http://drupal.org/project/pageflip). Can any one suggest the module which I am searching?

The existing Pageflip module is still a beta version; I need a module that has a stable release.

Comment: Beta5 is usually stable enough to use in production.

Comment: What do you mean approved ? No one approves any module on drupal , always use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kantu's comment suggests, there is no formal "approval" system for modules on drupal.org.  Instead, module maintainers decide when to release their modules and what version number to assign them.

As pageflip is a highly specialized module, I doubt that there is another module that has similar functionality (a quick search returned none).  However, since it is beta 5, it is probably stable enough to use in production, as Countzero pointed out.  The alternative would be to write a module yourself, but since the pageflip module is already far along in its development it would probably be best for everyone if you would extend and contribute back to the pageflip module (assuming you were going to write your own module).

How do you really know whether the module is ready for production?  First, look at the [list of open reported bugs](http://drupal.org/project/issues/pageflip?categories=bug).  In this case there are only 3 for the 6.x series, so it shouldn't take you very long.  If these bugs don't affect you, the module is probably safe to install.